# Custom sorting dynamic table, how to perform a postback on header cell click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to make a sorting ability on a table. I used the Jquery sorting for a while but now I'm forced do do this server side and not on the HTML itself.

I have a asp table with tableHeaderCell. Unfortunately this header cell doesn't have an onclick property.

What i would like to do:
When the user clicks anywhere on the header the page does a post back and changes the query it selves.

**What's the best way to trigger a post back when there is clicked on an header cell?**

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tbl_main" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" GridLines="Both" BackColor="White" class="tablesorter">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="#CEE3F6" ForeColor="White" Wrap="false" Width="50px"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NoImage">
        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="#CEE3F6" ForeColor="Black" Wrap="false" Width="100px"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            col1 

        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="#F78181" ForeColor="Black" Wrap="false" Width="250px"
            HorizontalAlign="Center">
            col2

        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
   </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do : you add a onclick function inside your header. This has to call a javascript function.

In this javascript function, you should use $().ajax() : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

On success, you reload the whole table with your new data.

Comment: I can't add OnClick="alert(); or OnClientClick="alert(); in <asp:TableHeaderCell or <asp:TableHeaderRow

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){$('.yourrow').attr('onclick', 'yourfunction();');